# Reverse harem isekai novel where mc can heal monster contamination/sickness

Tags: story-identification, isekai, hentai

Does anyone know this isekai novel? A woman isekais into a world where contact with monsters from the forest (?) causes people to get sick/contaminated and turn into mindless beasts themselves but she has the ability to heal them with her blood. Because of this she is forced by the "priest" of that time to go to different places and heal people despite the effecton her body. She is neglected but afraid to stop helping because they will kill her to summon a new priestess/healer (?) from another world.
At this time she meets and gets into a physical relationship with the prince. He says he loves; however, he gets engaged to marry a woman of higher status. The woman basically gives permission for her to be his woman on the side and everyone acts as though she should be grateful. She is heartbroken and during one of her trips to heal others, her carriage falls/hangs off of a cliff. Due to her sadness, she decides to no longer fight it and fall to her...
She doesn't die. That said, she's hurt, gets rescued by a handsome elf looking guy and in turn uses her ability to save him. This leads to being brought back to the elf guys home, where there are lots of single elf men, no women, and it turns out other bodily fluids can also help heal. And a reverse harem is born. Does anyone know the name of this one?
I came across it when I was half sleep so I cannot remember the name at all.

Please note I kind of remember them saying they were not elves. However, being that she is from the modern world she described them as having similarities to elves. Also, I put ? or "" if I couldn't remember the exact term used for the world building.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure exactly where but it would have been on one of the web novel sites online. And it was over 3 months ago